# Excel formula reference error when data overwrites existing data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a formula that is reference a range in a different sheet in the same workbook. When the data in the source sheet is overwritten (but the sheet name stays the same), the formula breaks with a #Ref!

The formula is:

```
=INDEX(a_Test[[rangeColumnNameStart]:[RangeColumnNameEnd]], Match('sheetName'!F122, a_Test[ColumnToLookUp],0),1)
```

When the data is pasted into the a_Test sheet which overwrites the existing data, the formula changes to this:

```
=INDEX(#REF!,Match('sheetName'!F122,#REF!,0),1)
```

Im new to excel and formulas so any help would be appreciated

Comment: `a_Test` is the name of a Table, not just a sheet, so I suspect you are deleting the table.

Comment: That was the issue, Thanks!